# cellForRowAtIndexPath only called for objects that are added while allocating datasource

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, xcode4.3

I know there are a lot of such questions on stackoverflow but I couldn't find the answer to mine.

I am trying to populate my UITableView from an **Array that is a member of** DetailViewController: UITableViewController. Problem is that **I don't have values in that array at start**. After I get data from web I populate the array and then I expect that the UITableViewCells get populated automatically from that update in Array. Please note that I am initializing my array in ViewDidLoad() like

```
self->ArrToDisplay = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

I read somewhere that the numberOfRowsInSection shouldn't return 0. To accomplish that I initialized my array with empty string (that I really don't want to). After that, it did call cellForRowAtIndexPath once.

So in short problem is that cellForRowAtIndexPath gets called when I initialize array with objects but I want this function to get called once I add objects to array somewhat later when they are available. I am stuck with this problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: ArrToDisplay should be datasource array so when your ArrToDisplay gets filled successfully just call [self.tableView reloadData];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but I want this function to get called once I add objects to array
>   somewhat later when they are available.

Once the objects are added to the array, call the `reloadData` of the tableview as follows.

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked! I will accept the answer in few minutes.